# Plot time against date in asp.net chart control

Tags: c#-4.0, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-charts

Im using **System.Web.UI.DataVisualization.Charting**
for creating charts.

I want to plot different timevalues against the different dates

where Time values will be in Y axis and Date Values will be in X axis.

I tried using

```
     chart.Series[0].XValueType = ChartValueType.Date;
     chart.Series[0].YValueType = ChartValueType.Time;
```

For adding im taking from

```
     Dictionary<DateTime,DateTime>
```

and

```
     chart.Series[0].Points.AddXY(item.Key.ToOADate(),item.Value.ToOADate());
```

But it is giving a 45 degree line chart  but i want it like a trend Report.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually my mistake is, I added the items to  the series from the dictionary and then i gave the xvaluetype and yvaluetype

But now i fixed it by giving the xvalue type and yvaluetype before adding the item to the series.